# GWT in IE8 - Exception thrown and not caught in file *cache.html & but after reloading the page it works

Tags: internet-explorer, gwt, internet-explorer-8

I was reading some posts about this error but it looks like that none of them have the same error.
My application runs perfectly in chrome and firefox but today I got shocked when I realized that it didn't work in IE8.

Now comes the really fun part. When I access the application with IE8, I just see  a blank page (and the sign indicating an error at the bottom left), but when I refresh the website it works!!

So I think it must be something with the cache of IE. Because when I clear the cache, then it works for one time. When I enter the address in the browser again, it doesn't work anymore. After reloading the page it works again.

I found out that the 
problem should be something with RPC calls. 
So if a RPC call is being executed I get the java script error. Then I 
reload the the site and execute the RPC call again => it works. 
I hope someone can help me further.

Comment: Do you have <set-property name="user.agent" value="safari,gecko1_8" /> in your module configuration (*.gwt.xml)? This would prevent compilation of JavaScript code for Internet Explorer.

Comment: Can you explore the `jsFunction`? I think IE developer tools are confused about the "catch(e) { throw e; }". You could also try removing this try/catch.

Comment: @Flo I added <set-property name="user.agent" value="safari,gecko1_8" /> to my *.gwt.xml. I still have the same error.

Comment: @ThomasBroyer: what do you mean by exploring it. How can I remove the try/catch? The code is generated by gwt

Comment: By "exploring", I mean seeing which function it actually references (i.e. what's the value of the `jsFunction` argument), and then look it back into the code. And I don't understand why you couldn't edit the generated code; isn't it just a file on your disk?

Comment: @ThomasBroyer: sorry for my bad knowledge. I removed the exception. Now I don't get any errors, but now I just have blank page. I can only see the application when I press the 'Compatibility View' Button of the IE Browser

Comment: You mean that with `function entry_0(jsFunction) { return function() { return entry0(jsFunction, this, arguments); } }; }` (same as above,without the try/catch), you no longer see an exception, but the app doesn't work either? Very strange...

Comment: @mkn Do you use any thirdparty scripts, like maps?

Comment: I use this slider http://www.zackgrossbart.com/hackito/gwt-slider/ and this seems to be the problem. When I removed it everything works fine. The problem is only that I really really need a slider. SmartGWT provides a very ugly slider which is impossible to style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after all it looks like that using the slider of the jquery library produces the whole problem. Maybe jquery throws the exception but it get's handled when a RPC call is done...
Furthermore it looks like that when jquery is being cached by the browser it produces the error.

So after days of figuring out a solution I replaced the handsome jquery slider with a smartgwt slider.